# Trouble with an array declaration

Tags: c, declaration, strlen

I have a little problem with my code.
I am programming a C project and I need to declare a field of characters of exactly the same size as another one, the problem is anytime my initial string (secret) is longer than 7 chars it declares as 14 chars.
Here is the line:

`char guessedWord[strlen(secret)];`

Update, even if I declare it as:

```
char guessedWord[10];
```

And secret is longer than 7 it declares as 14, WTF? I thought that should be impossible... (using strlen for getting lenght)

The function goes like this:

```
    void hangman(const char secret[]) //Samotna hra
{
    int guesses=8; //zostavajuce pokusy
    int iteration=0; //iteracia
    char *lettersLeft="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //zostavajuce pismena
    char letters_guessed[ALPHABET_LENGHT]; //uz hadane pismena
    char input[100]; //vstupny znak
    char guessedWord[8]; //Zobrazene slovo

    for (int i=0; i < strlen(secret); i++) //inicializacia hadaneho slova
    {
        guessedWord[i]='_';
    }
    for (int i=0; i < ALPHABET_LENGHT; i++) //inicializacia zoznamu hadanych pismen
    {
        letters_guessed[i]='_';
    }

    printf("Guessed word init %s strlen of secret is %ld, secret is %s and strlen of guessedWord is %ld\n", guessedWord, strlen(secret), secret, strlen(guessedWord));
```

Comment: start by `char guessedWord[strlen(secret)+1]`. and second, we need to see a [mcve] because what you're saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where should I upload complete code?

Comment: not _complete code_, [mcve]. Shortest code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I used copy/paste, I corrected it

Comment: if you apply `strlen(guessedWord)` without initializing `guessedWord` you _could_ get 14 as the result of undefined behaviour. I don't know if I already asked you but [mcve] pretty please.

Comment: Added part of the function

Comment: Should be enough to see what is going on

Comment: yeah, now I see why. Check my answer.

Comment: I hope your aware that string in C is sequence of character byte with null termination in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char guessedWord[8]; //Zobrazene slovo

for (int i=0; i < strlen(secret); i++) //inicializacia hadaneho slova
{
    guessedWord[i]='_';
}
```

`strlen` doesn't interrogate the compiler to know the size of a literal/array (like you could do in some cases with `sizeof` but it has its limits). It just looks for the terminating zero, so it can work for any string (pointer on chars).

So, not nul-terminating your string can make `strlen` look for a zero outside the bounds of `guessedWord` (undefined behaviour)

You need to allocate the proper number of chars & null-terminate:

```
int len = strlen(secret)
char guessedWord[len+1]; //Zobrazene slovo
int i;
for (i=0; i < len; i++) //inicializacia hadaneho slova
{
    guessedWord[i]='_';
}
guessedWord[i] = '\0'; // i == len here
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the strlen function more thorougly.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct once timer runs out

Comment: thanks. And you've started to learn how to ask a good question now: not too few information, and not a "wall of code".

Comment: Well it is hard sometimes to get the right amount of code because you have no idea where the error is XD thanks again